# .htaccess cache static content (unless modified)?

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

Was wondering is this possible in .htaccess?

I'm currently caching .js, .css and all image files via PHP (and providing the cached only if the file has not been modified by checking the filemtime()).

However someone suggested it's possible via .htaccess and much faster, so was hoping maybe someone can shed some light...I've looked around and found various snippets but none which cover what I'm after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've got [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) installed on your apache server you can put something like this in your `.htaccess` file. This example is PHP orientated (actually grabbed from the Drupal 7 `.htaccess` file) but should serve as a good starting point.

```
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what would happen if the cache content was modified would it still retrieve the cached content until the cache is cleared, or automatically update?

Comment: Apologies I didn't read that bit fully, I've updated the code above to include the FileETag identifier at the top, it tells the server not to send a full response if the content hasn't changed. There's a [fuller explanation here](http://stuntsnippets.com/etags-htaccess/), but the idea is that if the content has changed the new content will be returned.

Comment: Awesome so with that snippet, it would cache all non .php files (such as static) for 2 weeks, and if the files have been modified it will automatically return the modified version?

Comment: Yup :) Any client that sends the `If-Match` header (which most if not all modern browsers do) will be able to take advantage of the caching feature. Have a quick read of the [Wikipedia entry on ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), it gives a good overall description of their use